# how to insert the xml data to sql server using c#?

Tags: sql, xml, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I am beginner to the C#, I need to insert my XML file to SQL table pro-grammatically XML file have five nodes called root, name, subject, sno and queries, I will listed below

```
<root>
<name>
MyName
</name>
<subject>
newsubject
</subject>
<queries>
<sno>
1
</sno>
<query>
This is the query one
</query>
</queries>
<queries>
<sno>
2
</sno>
<query>
This is the query two
</query>
</queries>
<queries>
<sno>
3
</sno>
<query>
This is the query three
</query>
</queries>
</root>
```

I need to add this value to sql server table name member_info

```
my table design is 
name --> varchar(50)
subject-->varchar(75)
sno-->int
queries-->varchar(150)
```

I tried some basic stuffs for finding the XML file on the specific folder, I don`t have idea how to implement by reading and inserting XML file, Please be gentle I am just beginner.

Comment: Your xml hierarchy doesn't make a lot of sense.  Wouldn't you  want a single <queries> root node, and then all subsequent <query> nodes under it?  Do you want a row into member_info for each query?  Should all queries under <root> be for a single member_info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options:

- You can read the XML nodes before inserting into the database, and
  insert normalized table column values.
- You can shred the XML in a stored procedure, by passing the XML
  string as an input parameter.  You can read up on how to shred the XML utilizing the nodes() method, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx).